# How to quickly change instruments in LMMS using LX61+ onboard keys/present

Tags: midi, workflow, instruments

I want to quickly switch instruments on LMMS using only onboard keys (Instr/Preset/MIDI channels/messages) on my LX61+. The keyboard manual describes presets very briefly, not describing such an example.
Is there any way to achieve such a thing using one button (circular) or combination of two buttons (up/down) to quickly switch the instruments?